# Discord.js Avatar command

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Hello i am trying to make command to show pfp of mentioned person but i am stuck with that

[image]

The code that i am using is this 
and has no errors

```
case 'avatar1':

                    const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
                    const avatarEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                        .setColor("RANDOM")
                        .setAuthor(user.username)
                        .setImage(user.avatarURL);
                    message.channel.send(avatarEmbed);

                break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<User>.avatarURL` is a method, therefore it would be `<User>.avatarURL()`

Documentation: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=avatarURL

Comment: It seems like you're looking for .displayAvatarURL() then https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=displayAvatarURL